# How to share category model for user model and customer model?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, relational-database

I am new to Laravel. I am building application for accounting system.

I want to have model for User and Customer, every model has the category_id column. but I don't want to create every Category Model for each models. I want to have the one Category Model that contain both category of User and Customer Model.

Example:

**User Model's Column**

```
- id
- name
- category_id
```

**Customer Model's Column**

```
- id
- name
- category_id
```

**Category Model's Column**

```
- id
- name
- type (user or customer)
```

***-----Updated------***

Example:

**Category Model**

```
**ID - NAME - TYPE**
1 - staff - user 
2 - visitor - user 
3 - owner - user 
4 - new - customer
5 - old - customer
```

so when we create user/customer we will get (staff, visitor, owner) category for user and (new, old) category for customer.

To archive this relationship, which Eloquent Relationship should I implement?

Comment: You might be looking for https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#polymorphic-relations

Comment: thanks for your comment, I have tried the Polymorphic Relations already, but there are the problem with categotable_id, because we only need to create one category item as it will be reusable. please help to check in the updated* example section.

Comment: Can't you do a query `Category::where('type', 'user')->pluck('name')` to get the category related to the type. No need of a polymorphic relationship, if there is gonna be a common category

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to define a type. `Category` model should know nothing about a user type. Just define two relationships in the `Category` model:

```
public function users()
{
    return $this->hasMany(User::class);
}

public function customers()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Customer::class);
}
```

You also can define the relationship both in `User` and `Customer` models:

```
public function category()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Category::class);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. it is working well when we want to retrieve the category of user/customer that we are in. But how can we get all categories of user/customer? I want to get all categories because we will need it when we create the user/customer.